# how to get media element to work in universal app?

Tags: vb.net, media-player

i try get media element to work with the is universal application on windows, but not working, i cant not select source, its not working like other version WPF, thanks for time.

```
mediaElement.Source = New Uri("C:\Users\User\My Videos\Movie.mp4", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
```

this work ok, but not in universal.
its not playing or evening getting the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows Universal, it doesn't work the same way as it would in WPF, I had the same problem a few weeks ago, with that being said, you need to import the picker from Windows.Storge.Pickers, its kind like openfiledialog and use the following example i have quickly done for you.
Change it around to suit your needs.

```
Imports Windows.Storage.Pickers


Private Async Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button1.Click

    Dim OpenFileDialog1 = New FileOpenPicker
    OpenFileDialog1.CommitButtonText = "Play"
    OpenFileDialog1.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4")
    OpenFileDialog1.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.HomeGroup

    Dim Movie = Await OpenFileDialog1.PickSingleFileAsync
    If Movie IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim SelectedMovie = Await Movie.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read)
        mediaElement.SetSource(SelectedMovie, Movie.ContentType)
        mediaElement.Play()
    End If
End Sub
```

If you have any problems with it, let me know and i will be happy to help you out, also dont forget to have the button & mediaelement component dragged to your windows form/designer, Happy Coding!